# How to get public methods from Dll using C# when publickeytoken == null

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, publickeytoken

I want to find Public userdefined function from a dll when `publickeytoken == null`

```
OpenFileDialog obj = new OpenFileDialog();
if (obj.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(obj.FileName);

    // Here its getting Exception because Publickeytoken == null;
    Assembly a = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(ass.FullName);

    Type[] types = a.GetTypes();
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        if (!type.IsPublic)
        {
            continue;
        }

        MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public
                                                | BindingFlags.Instance
                                                | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod);
        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.Name + "." + member.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

How to solve this

Even i Tried this to Find publictokenkey it retruns 
                    0 bytes

```
           byte[] b = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().GetPublicKeyToken();
```

Comment: What is your exception ? Also, LoadWithPartialName is obsolete, you should use Load instead.

Comment: Why don't you use the assembly object "ass" directly? since you just loaded it from the dll?

Comment: Ok tell me a solution to find public methods from Dll

Comment: Check the example here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding flags are wrong and you can use `ass` directly:

```
OpenFileDialog obj = new OpenFileDialog();
if (obj.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(obj.FileName);
    foreach(var type in ass.GetTypes())
    {
        MethodInfo[] members = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (MemberInfo member in members)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.Name + "." + member.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For Some Dlls its Working... Some its not working ? what i can do

Comment: I am getting this   See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

Comment: ************** Exception Text **************
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()

Comment: surroung it with try catch (the foreach(var type...) statement), have a look at the loaderExceptions to get more information